# If parent feeds (import) node is unpublished, how do I not include it in the import schedule?

Tags: 7, feeds

If the parent feed imports a node (the form/node to input the feed URL, not the feeds importer) that is unpublished, I'd like to have it (the feed URL) not be included in the cron schedule to update/import the feed items. How is this done? For example, a user submits a feed, but the administrator needs to verify it before publishing, and importing it.

See also [Don't import items if parent feed is unpublished](http://drupal.org/node/1195484).

Comment: Have you had any luck figuring this one? I tried this with the default (RSS) Feed Importer and it seemed to work as expected -- it didn't import when the feed node was unpublished.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. One of my feed importer is configured to use Common Syndicate Parser and the other one uses QueryPath Parser. I confirmed that the feed node (parent) is unpublished. Did you see the note that it's importing feeds on a cache flush -- is that odd or normal? It shouldn't do that regardless of status, right? I'm on a local so cron isn't set up yet.

Comment: The linked article has much better information, even sample code. Please consider adding that to the question here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, when a node is saved, Feeds module starts importing the feed from that node.

```
function feeds_node_insert($node) {
  // Source attached to node.
  feeds_node_update($node);
  if (isset($node->feeds) && $importer_id = feeds_get_importer_id($node->type)) {
    $source = feeds_source($importer_id, $node->nid);
    // Start import if requested.
    if (feeds_importer($importer_id)->config['import_on_create'] && !isset($node->feeds['suppress_import'])) {
      $source->startImport();
    }
    // Schedule source and importer.
    $source->schedule();
    feeds_importer($importer_id)->schedule();
  }
}
```

There is an option in the importer's setting page called **Import on submission**. If you uncheck this box, hopefully your feed won't be imported.  Feeds maintainer still need to make changes in feed_cron() so that it won't fetch the unpublished nodes.

While you wait for a better fix from module maintainers, you can quickly fix this code by changing the first if statement to add **$node->status==1**  condition as follows:

```
if ($node->status==1 && isset($node->feeds) && $importer_id = feeds_get_importer_id($node->type))
```